# CordovaError: Platform ios already added

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, taco

I am running on OS X El Capitan.  I am working with VSTS and have the TACO plug installed and also have an ios agent running.

I am following these steps trying to build for IOS.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/cordova-build

I have an agent running in interatice mode:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-osx

However, the Cordova build step is failing and I cannot understand why after checking all the steps a few times.  See bolded error.

> ***************************************************************************** Finishing: npm install
>
> ---
>
> ****************************************************************************** Starting: Cordova Build ios
>
> ---
>
> ============================================================================== Task         : Cordova Build Description  : Build a hybrid app project
>   based on the Cordova CLI, Ionic CLI, TACO CLI, or other
>   Cordova-compliant CLI Version      : 1.3.9 Author       : Microsoft
>   Corporation Help         : [More
>   Information](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=691186)
>   ============================================================================== DEVELOPER_DIR was undefined DEVELOPER_DIR for build set to
>   /Applications/Xcode8.0.app/Contents/Developer Input to
>   determineIdentity:
>
> ```
>  1 valid identities found
> ```

XXX

> (YGKU7EWJD4)","keychain":"/Users/jordanmc/Documents/repos/myApp/1/s/_tasktmp.keychain"}
>   Input to determineProfile:
>   XXX Got rid of som sensitive info
>   Module cache at /Users/jordanmc/.taco_home/node_modules cordova
>   already installed. Adding Xcconfig update hook Module cache at
>   /Users/jordanmc/.taco_home/node_modules cordova already installed.
>   Adding support plugin. cp: no such file or directory:
>   /Users/jordanmc/Documents/repos/myApp/resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png
>   cp: no such file or directory:
>   /Users/jordanmc/Documents/repos/myApp/resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png
>   Removing Xcconfig update hook { CordovaError: Platform ios already
>   added.
>       at /Users/jordanmc/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/6.4.0/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform.js:130:31
>       at _fulfilled (/Users/jordanmc/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/6.4.0/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/jordanmc/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/6.4.0/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/jordanmc/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/6.4.0/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
>       at /Users/jordanmc/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/6.4.0/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
>       at flush (/Users/jordanmc/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/6.4.0/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7) Task failed
>   **>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)   name: 'CordovaError',   message: 'Platform ios already added.',
>
>   code: 0,   context: undefined }**
>   ****************************************************************************** Finishing: Cordova Build ios
>
> ---
>
> ****************************************************************************** Starting: Post Job Cleanup
>   ****************************************************************************** Cleaning any cached credential from repository: XXX
>   ****************************************************************************** Finishing: Post Job Cleanup
>
> ---
>
> ****************************************************************************** Finishing: Build
>
> ---

I have this configured:
[image]

Any help would be great!

Comment: I am having this error Platform android already added.

Comment: Also i am facing this same error in Ionic Project. When i am trying to create ionic ios platform
Command: ionic platform add ios
Error: Platform ios already added.

Comment: ooh just resolve the issue. Just Logout Apple & close terminal. Again run the project. Now adding ios platform successfully.